# Extract brewing with Coopers LME

Tags: extract-brewing

At present I do not really want to boil up any grains so I thought some Coopers Malt Extract which is unhopped.

Is it a step up from a kit so I can add my own hops without having to boil grains? I'm happy with boiling the hops.

Answer (score 2):

Yes: you can add your own hops while boiling malt extract.

It's not really a "step up" or a "step down".

(Also, FTR, you almost never "boil" grain … you can either steep it or mash it, but it should not be boiled (unless you're talking about decoction mashing, but that's not what you're talking about).)